# Thirdparty API invoke from Web Service (ASMX)

Tags: c#, jquery, web-services, asp.net-ajax

I've got a scenario to invoke an API from a third party application. But since the request is by using HTTPClient, its async and thus I'm not able to return correct value to Ajax request.

Here is my code

```
    [WebMethod]
    public string getSampleData()
    {

        string url = "https://api.thirdparty.com/eport/?Key=200&resultsPerPage=1000";


        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler())) 
        {
            var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("sabcd@test.com:TEst12345");// ("sabcd@test.com:Pwd123"); 
            string val = System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + val);

            ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

            try
            {
                using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url))
                {
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                    string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    string k = responseBody;
                    return k;
                }
                return "";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ex.Message;
            }


        }


    }
```

But it simply triggering error since **await** does not work there. So how can I deal with the situation wisely without any trouble.

Here is my AJAX call
        $('#btn_keyedin').click(function () {

```
        $.ajax({
            url: '../webservice1.asmx/getSampleData',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            datatype: 'JSON',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            },
            error: function () {
            }
        });
    });
```

Please help to solve this trouble

Comment: For synchronous methods you could use GetAsync(url).GetAwaiter().GetResult(). That does quite the same await does, but synchronously

Comment: "But it simply triggering error since await does not work there.". What is the error?  Is it a compile-time or a run-time error?

Comment: @SirOneOfMany Thanks a lot mate.. That worked like a charm!

Comment: @OguzOzgul The error is obvious since an await in a non-async function. Thats why I didnt specifed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`await` keyword can only be used in `async` methods. As far as I know, `WebMethod` cannot be async. You will have to change your `await`s to `.Result` or as other people said `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`.